# Remove i:nill="true" from a request

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building a WCF client that consumes the eVerify webservice offered by the Dept. of Homeland Security. This service publishes a WSDL and schema. The schema specifies that elements can be nillable. For example

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="FirstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

Unfortunately I am being told by DHS support that the service cannot handle an incoming element on a request that follows this schema. Specifically I am being asked to remove i:nil="true" from elements like the example below

```
<FirstName i:nil="true"/>
```

Ideally DHS wants to see

```
<FirstName><FirstName>
```

Is there a way for me to accomplish this in a run of the mill WCF client using Visual Studio 2013 ?

Comment: Leave it to a government agency to publish a WSDL and then not follow it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way probably is to download the WSDL & XSDs, edit them locally, and generate your proxy classes on the patched version. You can do this with `svcutil`:

1. `svcutil /t:metadata URL` ([How to: Use Svcutil.exe to Download Metadata Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751847(v=vs.110).aspx))
2. `svcutil YourWsdlFile.wsdl *.xsd`
   Note that when using `svcutil` on local files, no `<import>` declarations in the WSDL are resolved; that's why you need to specify all XSDs on the command line as well. However you can use wildcards as shown for convenience.

Comment: Does that also mean I need to change the endpoint config to no longer point to the service wsdl as published by DHS, and instead point to a local copy?

Comment: No, you still want to call the real service. :) Use the Something.cs file created by the described steps to replace your existing proxy classes, leave everything else as is. (If you used "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio for proxy generation, remove that reference and include the new .cs file in your project.)

Comment: I am marking the answer as correct however I want to note that while working through the usage of svsutil I found that I can actually solve the problem in a simpler fashion - by passing String.Empty. Its an odd solution but it works.

Comment: Ah, good point. It's actually not that odd when you think of it - `string.Empty` represents a value, it just happens to be an empty string. `null` (or `i:nil="true"` in an XML) however represents the *absence* of a value. While it may look similar to humans, the two are very different things for a computer. ;)